# AP wifi => Freeradius (Pfsense) => ldap

Tags: openldap, freeradius

I have a autentication working for a user (in the ldap) on a :

> AP wifi => Freeradius (Pfsense) => ldap

I would like to have the folowing autentication working :

> user1 on SSID-wifi1 => Freeradius (Pfsense) => ldap
>
> user2 on SSID-wifi2 => Freeradius (Pfsense) => ldap

with "user1" menberof "SSID-wifi1" group in ldap
and "user2" menberof "SSID-wifi2" group in ldap

It works if I set the filter in freeRadius for ldap with

> (&(uid=%{User-Name})(|(memberOf=cn=SSID-wifi1,ou=group,dc=mydomaine,dc=net)(memberOf=cn=SSID-wifi2,ou=group,dc=schugart,dc=net)))

but of course both user have access to both SSID...

I would like to use the folowing filter :

> (&(uid=%{User-Name})(memberOf=cn=%{NAS-Identifier},ou=group,dc=mydomaine,dc=net))

but with this configuration the autentication fail...

I have check with wireshark (with the 1rst filter allowing wifi1 or wifi2), the AP wifi send the Nas-Identifier in all message send to freeRadius.

But in freeRadius exchange with ldap :

```
0.000000        192.168.0.radius        192.168.0.ldap          LDAP    1283    searchRequest(2) "dc=mydomain,dc=net" wholeSubtree
0.001206        192.168.0.ldap          192.168.0.radius        LDAP    151     searchResEntry(2) "cn=user1,ou=user,dc=mydomain,dc=net"
0.001240        192.168.0.ldap          192.168.0.radius        LDAP    80      searchResDone(2) success  [2 results]
0.008661        192.168.0.radius        192.168.0.ldap          LDAP    116     bindRequest(1) "cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=net" simple
0.009042        192.168.0.ldap          192.168.0.radius        LDAP    80      bindResponse(1) success
0.009098        192.168.0.radius        192.168.0.ldap          LDAP    73      unbindRequest(4)
0.237144        192.168.0.radius        192.168.0.ldap          LDAP    1265    searchRequest(3) "dc=mydomain,dc=net" wholeSubtree
0.237635        192.168.0.ldap          192.168.0.radius        LDAP    151     searchResEntry(3) "cn=user1,ou=user,dc=mydomain,dc=net"
0.237654        192.168.0.ldap          192.168.0.radius        LDAP    80      searchResDone(3) success  [2 results]
```

the searchRequest(2) has the Nas-identifier fill correctlly

but the searchRequest(3) has the Nas-identifier empty ...

**1rst question, why is there 2 time the searchRequest ?**

**2nd question, any idea why the second search filter has not the Nas-Identifier?**

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the problem but found a way tio do it working...

in the ldap file of radius declare 2 ldap serveur with different fileter :

> ldap ldap1 {
> ...
>
> ```
>    user {
>             filter = "(&(uid=%{User-Name})(memberOf=cn=SSID-wifi1,ou=group,dc=mydomain,dc=net))"
> ```
>
> ......
>
> ldap ldap2 {
> ...
>
> ```
>    user {
>             filter = "(&(uid=%{User-Name})(memberOf=cn=SSID-wifi2,ou=group,dc=mydomain,dc=net))"
> ```
>
> ......

in the "sites-enabled/inner-tunnel-peap.save" in the authorize section :

> ```
>     if (&NAS-Identifier == "SSID-wifi1") {
>        ldap1
>     }
>     if (&NAS-Identifier == "SSID-wifi2") {
>        ldap2
>     }
> ```

and in the "sites-enabled/default" comment ldap lines